# Single RAID5 disk recovery Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mdadm, raid5

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server, happily running 2 RAID1 arrays.

I have a load of old disks that I want to check before deciding whether to backup before destroying.

I am connecting the disk to the server via a SATA to USB caddy.

Some of the disks were part of a RAID5 array, and I only have a single USB caddy, so I am attempting (hoping) I am at least mount them to be able to check the contents - I only read a read-only view.

After connecting the disk `lsblk` gives:

```
sdf      8:80   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdf1   8:81   0 290.2M  0 part
├─sdf2   8:82   0 486.4M  0 part
├─sdf4   8:84   0     1K  0 part
├─sdf5   8:85   0 133.3M  0 part
└─sdf6   8:86   0 464.8G  0 part
```

With `fdisk -l` I get:

```
 fdisk -l /dev/sdf
Disk /dev/sdf: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: 00AAKS-00A7B0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xce16e76e

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdf1            63    594404    594342 290.2M 83 Linux
/dev/sdf2        594405   1590434    996030 486.4M 83 Linux
/dev/sdf4       1590435 976768064 975177630   465G  5 Extended
/dev/sdf5       1590498   1863539    273042 133.3M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdf6       1863603 976494959 974631357 464.8G 83 Linux

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

In `cat /proc/mdstat` I see:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md123 : inactive sdf6[0](S)
      487315584 blocks

md124 : inactive sdf1[2](S)
      297088 blocks

md125 : inactive sdf2[1](S)
      497920 blocks

md126 : active raid1 sdg2[1]
      1932533488 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]

md127 : inactive sdh1[0](S) sdg1[1](S)
      41961600 blocks
```

I try to scan then assemble and mount :

`mdadm --detail --scan /dev/md123`

gives:

`INACTIVE-ARRAY /dev/md123 metadata=0.90 UUID=9b990924:10915d87:0073689c:05407c1c`

Running `mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md123 /dev/sdf6`

`mdadm: /dev/sdf6 is busy - skipping`

Trying to mount:

`mount /dev/md124 /mnt/usb/usb6`

`mount: /mnt/usb/usb6: can't read superblock on /dev/md124.`

I tried running foremost to recovery but it dumps files of the same type into a folder and does not preserve names.

`foremost -dvT -i /dev/sdf6 -o /mnt/md0/share01/Backups/aa`

What else can I do to try and get the disk mounted so I can get the contents?

I understand that RAID5 is not a substitute for backup - but any help would be great.

Update

Output of `mdadm --examine /dev/md*`  (for this disk):

```
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :       594342 sectors at           63 (type 83)
Partition[1] :       996030 sectors at       594405 (type 83)
Partition[3] :    975177630 sectors at      1590435 (type 05)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : c095f89e:9b0361e2:811403e5:de6bdc08
  Creation Time : Fri May 30 10:44:30 2008
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 297088 (290.13 MiB 304.22 MB)
     Array Size : 297088 (290.13 MiB 304.22 MB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Jul 23 04:52:57 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : fab347e0 - correct
         Events : 871


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8        1        2      active sync   /dev/sda1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync
   1     1       8       17        1      active sync
   2     2       8        1        2      active sync   /dev/sda1
   3     3       0        0        3      faulty removed
/dev/sdf2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 368a4374:23c334f1:cb272099:0827c1c2
  Creation Time : Fri May 30 10:44:31 2008
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 497920 (486.25 MiB 509.87 MB)
     Array Size : 497920 (486.25 MiB 509.87 MB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Sat Jul 23 04:57:37 2011
          State : active
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 707d0f08 - correct
         Events : 54762505


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2

   0     0       8       34        0      active sync
   1     1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
   2     2       8       18        2      active sync
   3     3       0        0        3      faulty removed
/dev/sdf4:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :       273042 sectors at           63 (type 82)
Partition[1] :    974631420 sectors at       273105 (type 05)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdf5.
/dev/sdf6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 9b990924:10915d87:0073689c:05407c1c
  Creation Time : Fri May 30 03:26:54 2008
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 487315584 (464.74 GiB 499.01 GB)
     Array Size : 1461946752 (1394.22 GiB 1497.03 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 2

    Update Time : Sat Jul 23 12:45:47 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 10f1fb29 - correct
         Events : 20490276

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       38        0      active sync

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync
   1     1       8       54        1      active sync
   2     2       8       70        2      active sync
   3     3       0        0        3      faulty removed
```

Comment: `mdadm --examine /dev/sd*`? raid5 requires all drives to work, at most one may be missing, so a single raid5 drive is usually not mountable

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks. I've added the examine output. I am hoping that since `foremost` is able to `see` the data that there might be some utility that can be more usable in this situation.

Comment: well, what's up with the other drives? do they exist at all? it's a 4-disk raid5, you need at least 3... there's no way to work around that. with file carving, at most you'll find some tiny remnants (64K chunksize)

Comment: @frostschutz Hmm, I'll just have to get another 2 USB caddys for the other disks, as there is no quick dirty and cheap way to do this then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If those drives are old and small enough, and you have enough storage available to hold them all, you could also do one-by-one full disk copies (ddrescue) for each of them and then work with loop devices.